# How to add a regex to a gtkmm3 combo-box/Best way to grep a regex into a gtkmm3/c++ combo box?

Tags: regex, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am working on a project to list items of a file in a gtkmm combo box.

//I declared the signal handler as
void on_combo_changed();

//And the widget
Gtk::ComboBoxText m_Combo;

//All
void ABC::on_combo_changed()

I want to add a code that will only show the content of a file.
Example, a linux command would be grep -o \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,}\b /Documents/email/. How do I implement this on a combox box so when clicked it will show a list of emails?

Comment: Could you please be precise here? The content of the file is text including email addresses and you want to show all email addresses of this file in a Gtk::ComboBox?

Comment: That's correct. I want to list all the email addresses from the file in a Gtk::ComboBox. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, of course. But actually you have two parts to code here. First of all to parse the file and maybe add it to a vector, and then add the content of the vector to the ComboBox. Do you need help with both or is the ComboBox part clear?

Comment: Yes, if possible I would need help with both parts of the code as I am new to coding GTKMM application. Thanks.

Comment: I could walk you through, but that would be too much for the comments. Maybe change to chat?

Comment: Yes, sure. That would be great!